# How to format that computer?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bios, boot-partition, disk-formatting

I had Windows 10 with dual-boot Ubuntu. I wanted to remove everything and reinstall just Ubuntu.

I removed the Ubuntu partition in Windows and when I restarted, it didn't open and started with GRUB. I exited GRUB and there was a *remove everything* option. I selected that and when the percentage was 73 it stopped. Then I made a bootable Windows 10 USB and tried to format it, but there was another problem saying *Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key*.

I messed up  and don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: If you only want to install ubuntu, why did you make a bootable win10 usb?

Comment: I didn't expect to see the grub so I just wanted to turn back to the normal.

Comment: The Ububtu partition contaons files that Grub needs. So bu deleting it, you have killed Grub too. If you want to reinstall, keeping only one OS, boot from that OS's install media and use the whole disk from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) you can find a tutorial guide to installing Ubuntu on your computer.

When given the choice, select 'Erase disk' which will cause your computers hard drive to be completely erased and reformatted.

[image]

Comment: It worked, thank you.